# Why does my book use $\subseteq$ instead of $\subset$ to describe a transitive set?

Tags: notation, set-theory, ordinals

The following FOL statement is used in my book to describe a **transitive set** (which ultimately sets the stage for the definition of ordinals):

> $z$ is a transitive set *iff* $\forall y \in z [ y \subseteq z]$

Given that $y\subseteq z \leftrightarrow y \subset z \ \lor y=z $, I am a little confused as to why $y \subseteq z$ is used.

In the context of *ZFC* set theory, it is my understanding that $z \in z$ is always **false**.

Therefore if $y \in z$, then clearly $y \neq z$. So why not just use $y \subset z$?

Am I missing something? (There is clearly no logical issue either way...it just seemed odd).

Edit: After realizing that, perhaps, there are different definitions for the various symbols $\subset$, $\subseteq$, and $\subseteqq$, I figured I would add that my book (*The Foundations of Mathematics by Kenneth Kunen*) asserts the following definition:

> $x \subseteq y \iff \forall z ( z \in x \rightarrow z \in y)$

Also, it appears as though the only two subset symbols that are used in my book are $\subseteq$ and $\subsetneqq$ (the latter has no formal definition)...there is also $\nsubseteq$, but that is obviously not applicable here.

Comment: check if the author always uses $\subseteq$ instead of $\subset$; some authors simply use $\subseteq$ instead of $\subset$.

Comment: @dust05 oh, wow. I've been cruising through this book the whole time under the impression $\subseteq$ meant $y \subset z \ \lor y=z $. I assume $\subseteqq$ is, instead, what the author would write to convey $y \subset z \ \lor y=z $?

Comment: I don't know what book you are referencing, but In standard notion, $ \subset$ and $\subseteq$ are equivalent.

Comment: The book is "The Foundations of Mathematics" by Kenneth Kunen. The only reason I was somewhat hesitant to accept that $\subseteq \iff \subset$ is because when going through some ordinal proofs, the author says that "For all ordinals $\alpha, \beta: \ \alpha \subseteq \beta \leftrightarrow \alpha \in \beta \lor \alpha = \beta$", which to me suggests that $\subseteq$ is NOT the same as $\subset$

Comment: In standard notion, $x \subset y$ means $z \in x \implies  z \in y$; in this sense $x \subset y$ is equivalent to $x \subseteq y$. Now I guess that the definition of $x \subset y$  in your book is $z \in x \implies z \in y$ and $\exists z_0 \in y \wedge z_0 \not \in x$. Is it correct?

Comment: @dust05 I just scanned through the first 100 pages quickly. It appears as though the only symbols ever used are $\subsetneqq$ and $\subseteq$

Comment: Different authors use different notation. Traditionally yes, $\subset$ is used to mean $\subseteq$, and a distressingly large number of writers propagate that nonsense. More enlightened and intelligent authors are beginning to use the convention that $\subset$ specifically excludes equality. IMO it is far better to use $\subseteq$ and $\subsetneq$ as they are completely unambiguous, and hence not to use $\subset$ at all. Of course, the more cumbersome forms $\subsetneqq$ and $\subseteqq$ can also be found but I could never see the point in such overcomplication.

Comment: @PrimeMover good to know. Given the extra information that I have added to my question, it still strikes me as odd that the author has decided to use $\subseteq$ here instead of $\subsetneqq$

Comment: @S.Cramer Yes, that is indeed the question, which I don't feel able to answer adequately. But the statement as given is true, same as $\{1, 2, 3\} \subseteq \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ is true, even though it is a weaker statement than $\{1, 2, 3\} \subsetneq \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$. I don't think it's worth losing sleep over, but it is a sound observation and hence a good question to raise.

Comment: @S.Cramer I might even go so far as to suggest taking a look at Devlin's "The Joy of Sets" where he examines versions of set theory which do not adhere to ZF(C), and hence those in which the Axiom of Foundation does not hold. Sets may still be transitive in such contexts, so "$z$ is a transitive set *iff* $\forall y \in z: [y \subseteq z]$" now specifically includes the case where $y = z$.

Comment: @PrimeMover cool. That is sort of what I figured (i.e. Kunen giving "room" for more exotic set theories). Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the presence of the axiom of foundation, it is true as you indicate that no set belongs to itself, and so the definition of transitive set can be written with $\subset$ (or $\subsetneq$, whichever symbol you prefer).

*However*, one may study also set theories where foundation fails, and then it is natural to define transitive sets in a way that allows self-membership. Indeed, any set $\Omega$ such that $\Omega=\{\Omega\}$, for instance, should be considered transitive.

One minor thing is that the natural translation of the natural language statement describing transitive sets gives us the rendering used by Kunen: A set $t$ is transitive if and only if any element of $t$ is a subset of $t$. This description is agnostic as to whether containment is proper or not. A somewhat more mathematical observation is that, even if Kunen is working here in a context where foundation is assumed, the definition he gives can be ported as is to a setting where foundation fails, there is no need to redefine things in this new context. This "portability" is particularly useful if one finds oneself in a situation where only fragments of ZFC hold, which is typically the case when studying independence proofs (or using countable structures in combinatorial arguments).